# React Native FlatList Reorder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

So, i', using flatlist in my application, an I set the number of columns equal to two. All ok.
But its ordering this way:

1 2

3 4

5 6

There is someway to render this way ?

1 4

2 5

3 6

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also revise your post to include some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have the display you want. `Flatlist` renders the items depending order of your data with `numColumns` or by default.

In order to have your display, you can use `flexWrap: 'wrap'` style, but unfortunately you can use it with `Flatlist.`

In case if you don't need a `Flatlist` to display your data, this below the updated code from the [Flex Wrap](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#flex-wrap) documentation.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native"

const data = [
  "orangered",
  "orange",
  "mediumseagreen",
  "deepskyblue",
  "mediumturquoise",
  "mediumslateblue",
  "purple",
  "blue",
  "black",
  "pink",
  "red",
  "green",
  "gray"
]

export const App = () => {
  const [flexWrap, setFlexWrap] = useState("wrap")

  return (
    <PreviewLayout
      label="flexWrap"
      selectedValue={flexWrap}
      values={["wrap", "nowrap"]}
      setSelectedValue={setFlexWrap}
    >
      {data.map((value, index) => {
        return (
          <View
            key={`List_${index}`}
            style={[styles.box, { backgroundColor: value }]}
          >
            <Text style={styles.textBox}>{index}</Text>
          </View>
        )
      })}
    </PreviewLayout>
  )
}

const PreviewLayout = ({
  label,
  children,
  values,
  selectedValue,
  setSelectedValue
}) => (
  <View style={{ padding: 10, flex: 1, marginTop: 50 }}>
    <Text style={styles.label}>{label}</Text>
    <View style={styles.row}>
      {values.map(value => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={value}
          onPress={() => setSelectedValue(value)}
          style={[styles.button, selectedValue === value && styles.selected]}
        >
          <Text
            style={[
              styles.buttonLabel,
              selectedValue === value && styles.selectedLabel
            ]}
          >
            {value}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
    <View style={[styles.container, { [label]: selectedValue }]}>
      {children}
    </View>
  </View>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 8,
    backgroundColor: "aliceblue",
    maxHeight: 400
  },
  box: {
    width: 50,
    height: 80,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  textBox: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  button: {
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    paddingVertical: 6,
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: "oldlace",
    marginHorizontal: "1%",
    marginBottom: 6,
    minWidth: "48%",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: "coral",
    borderWidth: 0
  },
  buttonLabel: {
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: "500",
    color: "coral"
  },
  selectedLabel: {
    color: "white"
  },
  label: {
    textAlign: "center",
    marginBottom: 10,
    fontSize: 24
  }
})
```

[image]